# ADF Data Flows do not complete in debug mode

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I am building pipelines on Azure Data Factory, using the Mapping Data Flow activity (Azure SQL DB to Synapse). The pipelines complete in debug mode, when I enable sampling data for the sources. When I disable sampling data and run the debug, I make no progress in the pipeline. i.e. none of the transformations complete (yellow dot)

To improve this, should I increase the batch size from the source/sink (how do I determine a batch size), increase the number of partitions (how do I determine a good number of partitions)

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the Spark compute cluster you have set in the Azure Integration Runtime under data flow properties. Start there by creating an Azure IR with enough cores to provide RAM for your process. Then you can adjust the partitions and batch sizes. Much of the learnings in this area are shared here at this [ADF data flow performance guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance).

Comment: Thanks Mark. The error I am seeing on my data flows is that the transaction is aborted/rolled-back with a message that 'The wait operation timed out' caused 'Execution Timeout Expired'. 

My data flows are relatively simple (2 Azure SQL DB sources, minor transformations, union of both sources, and then sinked into Synapse), which is why the timeout makes no sense to me.

I've tried various sizes of compute cluster (from 8 - 80 cores)

Comment: That sounds like an error that is emanating from DW/Synapse when writing the data. Have you check your database?

Comment: I thought that, although the pipeline works for small amounts of data (<10k rows), but fails for the full data sets (100k to 100M rows). Maybe I need to scale up either my SQL DB and Synapse to a higher performance level, or maybe both?